# can access smb mount only with sudo

Tags: networking, mount, permissions, smb

I have mounted an external smb share on a 16.04.01 server, like that

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/fileserver
sudo mount -t cifs smb://myserver/sharename /mnt/myserver/sharename -o username=me, passwrd=123, ip="100.200.0.5"
```

At first i tried with smb://100.200.0.5/sharename and without the ip="..", because I did not have the server added to the hosts file and I had not dns et up. But that did not work. It would give me some very strange error (forgot it) and still seems very weird to me. But thats just a side note.

The mount itself is successful and I can access the share under

```
/mnt/myserver/sharename
```

but only as root! When I look at the permissions I get an output that I do not understand. Hopefully someone can explain that and what I need to do to access the share with my normal user

ls -l gives for myserver

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 13 11:00 myserver
```

ls -l gives for sharename

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 99 systemd-timesync 0 Feb 6 22:04 sharename
```

I guess the reason I can not access that sharename folder is because of the
"99" and "systemd-timesync". I would have expected that there also would be "root root". When I try to enter it without sudo I get:

```
cd sharename
-bash: cd: sharename/: Permission denied
```

Any explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have errors with your mount command.**  You have a "**-0**"  where it should be the letter "**o**" for options.  You can also add access and permissions to the options configuration.  You also spelled the filetype wrong.  It's **cifs** not **cif**.  Also the **smb:** part of your command is improper syntax for **mount**.  You'll have to remove it for the command to work properly.

Change your command to the following:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //myserver/sharename /mnt/myserver/sharename -o uid=1002,gid=100,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0660,username=me,passwrd=123,ip="100.200.0.5"
```

Replace the uid with the uid of your userid.

**Alternatively you can mount the share similar the way a file browser does** using **gvfs-mount**.  The command syntax is:

```
$ gvfs-mount smb://myserver/sharename
```

You will find that shared folder in:

```
/var/run/user/[1001]/gvfs
```

Replace the brackets and number with the number of your UserID.

The actual shared name in the folder would be something similar to:

```
smb-share:server=myserver,share=sharename
```

You could make a friendly name for accessing the share with:

```
$ ln -s /var/run/user/[1001]/gvfs/smb-share:server=myserver,share=sharename ~/sharename
```

After the symlink command you can access the share with:

```
$ cd ~/sharename
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to type the text from another screen and could not copy it. -0 and cif were typos, corrected the question. It would be nice if you could add info about where to get the gid100 number and the difference 0777 to the normal chmod 777 syntax. The man file for mount does only say "see options section of the mount.cifs(8). There it says uid and gid are not needed for servers(?). They do not explain what the numbers mean and where to get them from.

Comment: I can not use gvfs-mount, because I need to get that enstablished from a freshly installed server iso. The gvfs mount was not installed and not found. I found that in desktop that /var/run/user path is where the gui attached mounts are hidden. Personally, I do not like this cryptic user ID in the path, as I would never be able to memorize that - IMHO its quite unintuitive. I have not looked what ln does, but I shall do so. Thanks

Comment: @CatMan The **gvfs-mount** is from the package **gvfs-common**.  It's installed using `sudo apt install gvfs-common`.  You don't have to remember the cryptic name.  Just locat it in the `/var/run` folder one time.  It's not like there would be lots of files there.  Then link to it by a non-cryptic name.  The non-cryptic name is all you would have to remember.  All the steps that you are doing now, setting up paths and configuration is cryptic, but once you set it up once, you don't have to remember all the things you have to type in as in with the problems you're initially having.

Comment: @LDJames thanks for the info about gvfs-common. I would like to get the mount version running right now and currently it fails with "mounting cifs URL not implemented yet" I have not found a typo. Maybe I need to reboot. Can you explain why I get the "99" and "systemd-timesys" and what they mean?

Comment: The **gvfs-mount** would take care of all the permissions for you.  But for the more technical alternative of your current question, you can find your UID number with: `getent passwd | egrep [loginid]`.  Replace the word and brackets with the username you logged in with.  There isn't significant difference between 0777 and 777, except  that the four digits are the actual mask and the 0 is implied when it isn't stated.  You don't need many of the parameters for the server, but you can specify the effective mask on the commanline for convenience.

Comment: @CatMan You have to remove the **smb:** from the command.  Use the line included in my link, but changing to the masks and ID of your choice.

Comment: The **99** is coming from an arbitrary userID of that doesn't have a name associated with it.  You can specify the userID by using the parameters provided in my answer, if you want it to be specific.  You can use the command I provided in my previous command for finding the userID number and deciding which one to use.

Comment: Right, the command worked, I added for some reason smb://myserver and did not see it... The data for uid, gif also can be retrieved by typing "id". Thanks for your help and suggestions

Comment: Glad it worked! You're welcome.  You might consider accepting the answer so that other users of the community having a similar issue can see a workable solution.